# How to put a list of data from a for loop into a single array? i'm getting [item] [item] [item] this kind of variable...not [item, item, item]

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
function chartFunkcio(event) {
  let localData;

  if (localStorage.getItem('localData') === null) {
    localData = [];
  } else {
    localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localData'));
  }

  //get objects from array between mentioned dates
  var result = localData.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.date >= fromdate.value && obj.date <= todate.value;
  });
  var filtered = result;

  //Filtered object from array are sorted after dates
  var sortedd = filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
    var c = new Date(a.date);
    var d = new Date(b.date);
    return c - d;
  });

  for (i = 0; i < sortedd.length; i++) {
    var datesforchart = [];
    const pushedarray = datesforchart.push(sortedd[i].date);

    console.log(pushedarray);
  }
}
```

The local storage data is a tables data. I filtered that data after dates and then i sorted those dates. the sorted date are the one i would like to get in a single array like below mentioned.
i'm getting [item] [item] [item] this kind of data in console log...not an array like this[item, item, item]
i would need that array for implementing a chart, and for that i would neet that the array to look like this ["item", "item2", "item3"]

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65009933/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with example input and description of expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong inside the `for` loop.

```js
  for (i = 0; i < sortedd.length; i++) {
    var datesforchart = [];
    const pushedarray = datesforchart.push(sortedd[i].date);

    console.log(pushedarray);
  }
```

If you try to get new array with just `date` elements, you can replace the `for` loop with below code which uses `map` function.

```js
  var datesforchart = sortedd.map(function (item) {
    return item.date
  });

  console.log(datesforchart)

  // for (i = 0; i < sortedd.length; i++) {
  //   var datesforchart = [];
  //   const pushedarray = datesforchart.push(sortedd[i].date);

  //   console.log(pushedarray);
  // }
```